# Undefined data variable Vue.js when using axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

this is driving me nuts.

**I'm assigning the value from an axios response to my vue data like this:**

```
mounted() {
  axios
  .get('/campaigns/new.json')
    .then(response => (
      this.kits = response.data[0].kits,
     )
  )
```

**I can see with vue developer tools that my this.kits has an array of 8 items (correct)**

[image]

When I try to use `this.kits` afterwards or do `console.log(this.kits)`, I get **undefined or empty array**.

**What the hell am I missing?** Please help. Thank you

```
mounted() {
  axios
  .get('/campaigns/new.json')
    .then(response => (
      this.kits = response.data[0].kits,
      this.kitProducts = response.data[0].kitproducts,
      this.products = response.data[0].products,
      this.boxes = response.data[0].boxes,
      this.categories = response.data[0].categories,
      this.extras = response.data[0].extras,
      this.isCurrentUser = response.data[0].user,
      this.giftpacks = response.data[0].giftpacks
     )
  )
  console.log(this.kits)
```

`console.log(this.kits)` will output:

[image]

Comment: where are you doing console.log ?

Comment: @y.kaf. In my mounted() vue function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your console.log is being executed right after the promise request is initiated, you would have to place it at the end inside the `then` block or, as Nicola says, use async await

try this:

```
async mounted() {
  const response = await axios.get('/campaigns/new.json')
  this.kits = response.data[0].kits
  this.kitProducts = response.data[0].kitproducts
  this.products = response.data[0].products
  this.boxes = response.data[0].boxes
  this.categories = response.data[0].categories
  this.extras = response.data[0].extras
  this.isCurrentUser = response.data[0].user
  this.giftpacks = response.data[0].giftpacks

  console.log(this.kits)
}
```

Comment: Still using async I keep getting an empty array :(

Comment: check my edit, should work

Comment: had to remove the commas, haha

Comment: also, had forgotten the await, now it's correct, sorry

Comment: yeah, asynchronous can be tricky, but you'll get use to it

Answer (score 1):

Try to wait for your data. Move the API call to method:

```
methods: {
  async getData() {
    const res = await axios.get('/campaigns/new.json')
    this.kits = res.data[0].kits,
  }
}
```

and then in mounted hook:

```
async mounted() {
  await this.getData()
  console.log(this.kits)
}
```

Comment: No luck. Still I need to be able to use this.kits in my mounted and will show up as an empty array :(

Comment: @Gibson hey mate, did you try it? with async/await you should be able to see the data.

Comment: Nikola, tried it with no luck,  André answer worked using await, thanks a lot